# How to add a range of integer elements from a list? Python 3.3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sum

I know `sum(list)` works to add ALL the elements in a list, but it doesn't allow you to select a range.

ex:

```
l = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77]    
x = 4
```

In this case I want to add `l[0 : 4]` together.

I know I can do:

```
short_l = l[0 : x]
sum(short_l)
```

But is there a function that allows me to select the range of elements within a list to add together?

Comment: You want a function to select or a builtin function to select the range and add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create a sublist, you can use [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77]
>>> sum(itertools.islice(l, 0, 4))
110
```

Comment: Is there any way in which this is better than: `sum(l[slice(0,4)])` ?

Comment: @Gronk, `l[slice(0,4)]` returns a sublist, while `itertools.islice(l, 0, 4)` returns a iterator. In case the sublist is huge, `itertools.islice` is more memory-efficient. But for small sublist, the it will not make much difference.

Comment: @Gronk, `l[slice(0,4)]` is a just another way of expressing `l[0:4]`. (`l[0:4] == l[slice(0,4)]`)

Comment: The list grows up to over 12,000 elements so this is good to know.

Comment: @Gronk: Use `islice` if the slice is huge (12000 items is only 50 to 100 KiB -- a drop in the bucket), or if you're creating thousands or millions of slices that coexist on the heap. Otherwise using a regular slice will usually perform better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the builtin [`slice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) function to get the range of items, like this

```
l, x = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77], 4
print(sum(l[slice(0, 4)]))
# 110
```

The parameters to `slice` are the same as the [slicing syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1903116).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a new function anyways? Just do `sum(l[0:x])`. If you really want a function, you can define one yourself:

```
def sum_range(lst, end, start=0):
    return(sum(lst[start : end + 1]))
```

which adds from index start to end including end. And start is default to index 0 if not specified.